# Interactive Query

Tags: mysql, sql, interactive

Is there a way to create a query where as a user is prompted with a dialog to enter the value X to complete the following query:

```
SELECT X AS DISTANCE,
SUM(ABS(LOCX) <= X AND ABS(LOCY) <= X) AS QUANTITY,
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
CONCAT(AVG(ABS(LOCX) <= X AND ABS(LOCY) <= X)*100, '%') AS PERCENTAGE
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: Assuming MySQL, as it is a continuation of your Previous Question!

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct, I did not want to throw a whole bunch of questions in to one thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are coding an app wherein the user supplies the inputs, there are multiple ways to create a query that uses those values as variables - one way is as follows:

```
SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
SELECT @t1, @t2;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

So for your particular case, replacing all the instances of `X` with the MySQL syntax for a user-defined variable `@X`, it would look something like this:

```
SET @X = user_input;
SELECT @X AS DISTANCE,
SUM(ABS(LOCX) <= @X AND ABS(LOCY) <= @X) AS QUANTITY,
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
CONCAT(AVG(ABS(LOCX) <= @X AND ABS(LOCY) <= @X)*100, '%') AS PERCENTAGE
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: When entering this code, MyPHPAdmin simply returns an error, should this query prompt me for an input when executing?

Comment: solved, I was not reading your code correctly, thank you